# Beginner Rock, Paper, Scissors in Java

Tags: java, beginner, rock-paper-scissors

I was curious on what, if anything, I could be doing better. I have been spending the last few days working with Java and learning some basics and wanted to try this challenge and making it two classes. I found the scanner is sometimes strange and doesn't take input the first time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class rps {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        int input;
        int b = 1;
        Scanner sage = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rnd = new Random();
    System.out.println("Rock Paper Scissors, by Sage!");
    System.out.println("Select 1, 2, 3, for Rock, Paper, Scissors");
    //Menu Present, pretty bad still

        while (b != 0){
        int rock = 1, paper = 2, scissors = 3;
        input = sage.nextInt();
        int randomNumber = rnd.nextInt(3-1+1)+1;

            if(randomNumber == rock){
                if(input == rock){
                    System.out.println("Rock vs. Rock, ITS A TIE!");
            }    else if(input == paper){
                    System.out.println("Rock vs. Paper! You win!" );
            }    else if(input == scissors){
                    System.out.println("Rock vs. Scissors! You lose!");
            }  //These blocks establish options if the computer got Rock

            else if(randomNumber == paper){
                if(input == rock){
                    System.out.println("Paper vs. Rock! You lose!");
            }   else if(input == scissors){
                    System.out.println("Paper vs. Scissors! You win!");
            }   else if(input == paper){
                    System.out.println("Paper vs. Paper! Its a tie!");
            } //These blocks establish the options if comp. got paper

            else if(randomNumber == scissors){
                if(input == rock){
                    System.out.println("Scissors vs. Rock! You win!");
            }   else if(input == scissors){
                    System.out.println("Scissors vs. Scissors, ITS A TIE!");
            }   else if(input == paper){
                    System.out.println("Scissors vs Paper! You lose!");
            } //These blocks establish if the computer got scissors.

            }
            }
            rps2 rps2Object = new rps2();
            rps2Object.rps2();


        }

    }
    }
}
```

Then this is the other class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rps2 {
    public void rps2(){
        Scanner sage = new Scanner(System.in);
        int b;
        b = 1;
        System.out.println("Play again? Y(8), N(9)?");
        int yes= 8, no = 9;
        int input;
        input = sage.nextInt();

            if(input == yes){
                System.out.println("Rock,Paper,Scissors!");

            }else{
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
            }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of [rock-paper-scissors](/questions/tagged/rock-paper-scissors) implementations in [java](/questions/tagged/java) on this site.  I'll try to keep my suggestions at a [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) level, though.

First, I should point out that your **"play again?" mechanism** doesn't actually work: you ask the question, but never do anything with the result.    Putting the "play again?" prompt in its own class doesn't make much sense; it can just be a function.  That function should return a `boolean` result — `true` to play again, `false` to quit.  In `main()`, the `while (b != 0)` loop would best be written as a do-while loop, since you want to run the game at least once without asking.  `b` is a poor variable name; `playAgain` would be much more helpful.

The main lesson that I think you should learn from this exercise is **object-oriented thinking**.  Instead of `input` and `randomNumber`, how about thinking about a `HumanPlayer` and a `RandomComputerPlayer`, both of which can return a choice of "Rock", "Paper", or "Scissors" when asked to `play()`?  The code would better model the game.

To analyze the outcome, you have **enumerated all 9 combinations**.  Of those, three outcomes are ties, which can easily be detected.  It would also be better to group all of the winning outcomes and all of the losing outcomes together.

#### RockPaperScissors.java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RockPaperScissors {
    private static boolean playAgain(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("Play again? Y(8), N(9)?");
        switch (scanner.nextInt()) {
        case 8:
            System.out.println("Rock, Paper, Scissors!");
            return true;
        default:
            System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        RPSPlayer computer = new RandomComputerPlayer(new Random());
        RPSPlayer human = new HumanPlayer(scanner);

        System.out.println("Rock Paper Scissors, by 200_success!");
        do {
            String comp = computer.play();
            String you = human.play();

            System.out.printf("%s vs. %s", comp, you);
            if (you.equals(comp)) {
                System.out.println(", IT'S A TIE!");
            } else if ( ("Rock".equals(you) && "Scissors".equals(comp)) ||
                        ("Scissors".equals(you) && "Paper".equals(comp)) ||
                        ("Paper".equals(you) && "Rock".equals(comp)) ) {
                System.out.println("! You win!");
            } else {
                assert (("Rock".equals(comp) && "Scissors".equals(you)) ||
                        ("Scissors".equals(comp) && "Paper".equals(you)) ||
                        ("Paper".equals(comp) && "Rock".equals(you)));
                System.out.println("! You lose!");
            }
        } while (playAgain(scanner));
    }
}
```

#### RPSPlayer.java

```
public interface RPSPlayer {
    String[] CHOICES = new String[] { "Rock", "Paper", "Scissors" };

    /**
     * Returns one of "Rock", "Paper", or "Scissors".
     */
    String play();
}
```

#### HumanPlayer.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HumanPlayer implements RPSPlayer {
    private final Scanner scanner;

    public HumanPlayer(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    public String play() {
        System.out.println("Select 1, 2, or 3 for Rock, Paper, Scissors");
        int choice = this.scanner.nextInt();
        // Keeping things simple, not doing any validation here
        return CHOICES[choice - 1];
    }
}
```

#### RandomComputerPlayer.java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomComputerPlayer implements RPSPlayer {
    private final Random random;

    public RandomComputerPlayer(Random random) {
        this.random = random;
    }

    public String play() {
        return CHOICES[this.random.nextInt(CHOICES.length)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Code organization

You created two classes, but didn't explain why. Don't create a class unless you have a good reason to do so. Example valid reasons to create a class:

- model real world objects
- model abstract objects
- reduce complexity
- hide implementation details

I strongly recommend to read the book Code Complete (2nd edition). If you're impatient, you can jump directly to chapter 6, working classes.

I suggest to combine the two classes. In addition, try to split the functionality to smaller functions, each with a single responsibility, and a descriptive name. The main method should do almost nothing, just call other functions that do the real work, which will be explained by their names. Chapter 7 in Code Complete can help you with this point.

#### Variable declarations

It's best to declare variables right before you use them. Don't declare variables at the top of a function of they are not used until the middle. Especially, don't declare a variable at a broader scope, when it can be declared in a more limited scope. In particular, the `input` variable should be declared inside the `while` loop.

#### Naming

It's impossible to guess what's going on here without reading the implementation of the `rps2` class:

> ```
>        rps2 rps2Object = new rps2();
>        rps2Object.rps2();
> ```

Also note that the convention in Java is to use `PascalCase` for class names.

These are also very poor names:

> ```
>    int b = 1;
>    Scanner sage = new Scanner(System.in);
> ```

It's never a good idea to name program elements after your own name. `scanner` would be more appropriate, for example.

It seems the value of `b` never changes, your using it to write an infinite loop. The idiomatic writing style of an infinite loop is this:

```
while (true) {
    // ...
}
```

#### Usability

> ```
> "Play again? Y(8), N(9)?"
> ```

That is, enter 8 to mean yes, and enter 9 to mean no? It would be more natural to use y to mean yes and n to mean no.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to write my own little Rock Paper Scissors game just so you could see the same project from another fellow programmer's perspective.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created on 7/4/2016.
 *
 */

public class RockPaperScissors {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> computerMoves = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3); // Used to generate random number.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Infinite loop until broken by exit case.
        loop : while(true){
            System.out.print("Rock, Paper, Scissors, Exit >>> ");
            String move = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            Collections.shuffle(computerMoves); // Shuffles list to achieve random numbers.

            switch(move){
                case "rock" : determineWinner(computerMoves.get(0), "Tie", "You Lose", "You Win"); break; // if move is rock
                case "paper" : determineWinner(computerMoves.get(0), "You Win", "Tie", "You Lose"); break; // if move is paper
                case "scissors" : determineWinner(computerMoves.get(0), "You Lose", "You Win", "Tie"); break; // if move is scissors
                case "exit" : break loop; // if move is exit
                case "" : continue loop; // if move is blank
                default : System.out.println("Invalid Input"); // if move is none of the above
            }
        }
    }

    // Used in the interest of code re-usability
    private static void determineWinner(int computerMove, String m1, String m2, String m3){
        if(computerMove == 1){ // computer move is rock
            System.out.printf("Computer Chose Rock, %s%n", m1);
        } else if(computerMove == 2){ // computer move is paper
            System.out.printf("Computer Chose Paper, %s%n", m2);
        } else { // computer move is scissors
            System.out.printf("Computer Chose Scissors, %s%n", m3);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, whether my coding decisions were the absolute best for this situation or not, there are still a lot of things you can take from my code. I tried to reuse some of the same tools that you used so you wouldn't be too lost but I also tried to implement some new things you might have never used or seen before.

**Formatting:**

Take note of the curly braces in my code, they emphasize the actual "blocks" of code. Your code is very hard to read because of poorly placed braces. [Here is a link to another review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133862/cheapest-hotel-finder), the top answer goes a lot more in depth on curly braces placement and has some decent visuals as well. Also while on the topic of indentation you have a few silly indentations through out.

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
System.out.println("Rock Paper Scissors, by Sage!");
System.out.println("Select 1, 2, 3, for Rock, Paper, Scissors");
//Menu Present, pretty bad still
```

And

```
input = sage.nextInt();

        if(input == yes){
            System.out.println("Rock,Paper,Scissors!");

        }else{
            System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
        }
```

Indentations are generally only followed by open curly braces. Not sure if these were just copy paste issues but worth mentioning.

**Functionality:**

This line stands out the most I believe,

```
input = sage.nextInt();
```

It accepts the next Integer, if given anything other than an integer your application will crash. Most of the time its a good idea to have some sort of check in there and correct a user or at least stop them from crashing the program. I deal with this by accepting a string and checking all expected input with a switch case statement. If a user gives this application something other than the 5 expected inputs, it will correct them by saying "Invalid Input".

Another notable problem with your game is that it will never stop. int b in your rps class never changes. When asking the player if they want to continue, you will have to change int b so that it equals 0 for the game to stop. Because int b is in another class from rps2, you would reference it like so:

```
rps.b = 0;
```

**Conclusion**

These are just a few important things to keep in mind. I'm sure someone will touch on some of the others.

Comment: Appreciate it a ton! Format is definitely something I need to work on as it is horribly messy but the indentation rule of open curly braces will help more than you could imagine for me. I haven't even began to touch on strings yet. A lot of stuff in your program has been stuff I have not touched on but do understand to some degree, I love seeing it from another perspective. Once again, thank you for the input =).

Comment: I edited a few more comments in there to try and clear some things up. Happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

## General

1. Represent expressive game elements in extra classes (Players, Rock/Scissor/Paper, Result, Situation, ...) for OOP
2. Try to reduce case handling, use proper let structures work for you
3. Follow [JAVA conventions in Naming](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

## Code

I looked after a solution with less if statements and more expressive artifacts. I came up with this:

### Introduce a class "Situation"

This represents a game situation with the choice of each player:

```
public class Situation {


    private final String choice1;
    private final String choice2;


    public Situation(String choice1, String choice2) {
        this.choice1 = choice1;
        this.choice2 = choice2;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return choice1.hashCode() * choice2.hashCode();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        boolean equals = false;

        if (obj instanceof Situation) {

            Situation that = (Situation) obj;

            equals =    this.choice1.equals(that.choice1) 
                     && this.choice2.equals(that.choice2);

        }

        return equals;
    }


    public Situation invert() {
        return new Situation(choice2, choice1);
    }


}
```

It's a value object so recognize the immutability and hashcode/equals overriden.

One other thing is the invert method which is a convenience method to express the other side around.

You may consider to use "real" objects to represent "Rock", Scissor" and "Paper" instead of String-Objects.

### Introduce class "Result"

It represents the outcome of one round.

```
public enum Result {

    TIE, PLAYER1_WINS, PLAYER2_WINS

}
```

### Evaluate all possible situations

You can now easily provide a Set of possible winning situations to evaluate the winner.

```
public class RockScissorPaper {


    private Set<Situation> winSituations;


    public RockScissorPaper() {

        this.winSituations = new HashSet<>();

        this.winSituations.add(new Situation("Rock", "Scissor"));
        this.winSituations.add(new Situation("Scissor", "Paper"));
        this.winSituations.add(new Situation("Paper", "Rock"));

    }


    public Result evaluateWinner(Situation situation) {

        if (this.winSituations.contains(situation)) {
            return Result.PLAYER1_WINS;
        } else if (this.winSituations.contains(situation.invert())) {
            return Result.PLAYER2_WINS;
        } else {
            return Result.TIE;
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RockScissorPaper rockScissorPaper = new RockScissorPaper();

        System.out.println(rockScissorPaper.evaluateWinner(new Situation("Rock", "Rock"))); // --> TIE
        System.out.println(rockScissorPaper.evaluateWinner(new Situation("Scissor", "Paper"))); // --> PLAYER1_WINS
        System.out.println(rockScissorPaper.evaluateWinner(new Situation("Rock", "Paper"))); // --> PLAYER2_WINS

    }


}
```